# Bluetooth does not work after update

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

My bluetooth device stopped working after one of the updates a few months ago. Opening Settings -> Bluetooth shows nothing and i also cannot add a device.

In terminal typing "bluetooth" gives 'bluetooth = none (no device)'

What can i do to get this to work?

My laptop is an Acer Aspire V3-371

```
lspci -nnk outputs:
    Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e07d]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k

and lsusb outputs:
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0489:e076 Foxconn / Hon Hai
```

and

```
lsmod | grep ath - outputs:
ath3k                  17427  0 
bluetooth             446409  12 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
ath9k                 141379  0 
ath9k_common           25638  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              446521  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    29006  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              652777  1 ath9k
cfg80211              498458  5 wl,ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
```

Comment: i have the same problem my laptop is Lenovo Y50-70 :(